# Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tickets\ictso_main.php on line 22

Tags: php

This part of the code is where i get the error.. i followed all the structure in PHP coding. I am new at PHp but im a software developer using vb.net.. im transitioning my knowledge but can't quite figure out whats wrong here.. the errors says ** Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tickets\ictso_main.php on line 22 **

```
if (isset($_POST ['sendNow'])){
$digitx="0001";
$requester="Zoren";
$probs="Hello";
$callbkNo="Hi";
$dept="Hallo";

$query =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO tblrequest (TicketID, xRequester, xProblem, xDepartment, CallbackNo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$query=$query->bind_param('sssss',$digitx, $requester,$probs, $dept, $callbkNo);
$query->execute();  

$db->close();
```

}

[Click here for the screeenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ty0R.jpg)

Comment: Don't overwrite the variable.

Comment: what variable do you mean sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query->bind_param('sssss',$digitx, $requester,$probs, $dept, $callbkNo);
```

This statement (above) produces a Boolean Value as return to show that it has executed.

```
$query=$query->bind_param('sssss',$digitx, $requester,$probs, $dept, $callbkNo);
```

When you do the above step (WRONG!), it replaces your `$query` with a Boolean. You are then trying to call an execute function on that Boolean.

Please change to:

```
$query->bind_param('sssss',$digitx, $requester,$probs, $dept, $callbkNo);
```

and don't assign it again to `$query`.

Comment: Thank you sir.... damn i didn't see that one... im really sorry for this, i just started coding PHP yesterday and im totally a newbie at PHP web dev...what you said it works!!!!